# Favourited, migrated questions appear as having no answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

I was browsing through my favourite questions list, and noticed that, strangely, "What's Your Favorite [sic] Harmless Computer Practical Joke?", had no answers. That seemed funny, so I checked it out - it was migrated to SuperUser.

This seems a bit strange - should it show the number of answers on SuperUser, should it show that it has been migrated, or is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) again?

[image: demo]

Comment: It shows that it has been migrated: [closed] at the end of the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design. The 'stub' with no answers is left behind to redirect people that have a link or favorite to the old question to the new location.

The reason why it doesn't have the answers or answer count from the new location is because the sites are separate, and it's not possible to determine the answer count on the target site.

However, I do agree that there should be better notification that a question has been moved, rather than simply closed. Perhaps using `[migrated]` or `[moved]` would work better than `[closed]`?

Comment: Yeah, something along those lines was what I had in mind. Should this be tagged by a mod now?