# Please append the reason for closing to the title along with "Closed"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, title

Came to mind when reading [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6975/favourited-migrated-questions-appear-as-having-no-answers/6977#6977), but would be useful for more than just moved, off-topic questions (I'd especially like to see duplicate questions flagged as such in the title).

Examples:

- [What should the penalty/response for missing a deadline be? [closed - Not programming related]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144703/what-should-the-penalty-response-for-missing-a-deadline-be-closed)
- [Stackoverflow won’t let me post? [closed - Belongs on meta]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148584/stackoverflow-wont-let-me-post-closed)
- [Data Module in DLL with Delphi? [closed - Duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148053/data-module-in-dll-with-delphi-closed)
- [VMWare Fusion / DHCP with multiple static IPs [closed - Belongs on SuperUser]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147912/vmware-fusion-dhcp-with-multiple-static-ips-closed)

Comment: I thought for a second this post was also closed.

Comment: Good idea! I should know, it's mine... ;-)

Comment: Steal from the best, i say...

Comment: i put [closed] in quotes for you so it won't look like this question is actually closed...

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is your edit what resolved the problem [discussed here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121270/chrome-redirect-loop-error-for-meta-question-link)?

Comment: @Bart: Yes, it is.  I had to use a [direct link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/6982/edit) to get an edit window so I could remove the quotation marks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

edit: my reason for declining this was bunk, however we did implement a different way:

Migrated questions will say `[migrated]` instead of `[closed]` now.

Comment: Agreed; if it is closed, it is largely a dead duck; let it alone. People can always go into the question for details.

Comment: The basic issue behind this, and several other question is that the current site visualization in not enough for many workflow patterns applied by the users. You might remember seeing a picture like this: http://twittch.com/26/ ?

Comment: The suggestion I made that prompted this was to change `[closed]` to `[moved]` or `[migrated]` for migrated questions. Since a closed question and a migrated question are two very different things, I still think it might be a good idea to differentiate them. Plus, it doesn't make the titles any longer.

Comment: And [duplicate] could similarly be useful without hurting readability.  (Many closed questions already don't have readable and useful titles anyway, so I'm not sure much is lost even with the verbose form of the feature request.)

Comment: If we use [moved] and other shorter titles, then it won't make the length much worse. take the question "will server-side programming be an taught differently in the future? [closed]" Now tell me what you will find when you look at the question. A link to a dupe? moved to SF? closed as subjective? There's no way to tell. The whole point of a title is to summarize a question, and just [closed] dismally fails at this....

Comment: I like @Kyle's suggestion and concur with @Crazy, when reading only question titles knowing whether a questions was closed as a dupe or may simply need to be improved and deserves a reopen vote then would spare the time of opening some closed questions...

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is a good idea.

I actually thought that this question was closed when I first saw it in the list though!

Answer (score 1):

Good concept, but It would make the title too long in some cases, perhaps an abbreviation would make things sorter. It is also possible, that the [closed] change is automated and not parameterable:

```
[closed - not programming related]   [XNP]
[closed - belongs on Serverfault]    [XSF]
[closed - belongs on Meta]           [XMT]
[closed - duplicate]                 [XD]
```

Comment: I would certainly *hope* the [closed] change is automated! If poor Geoff is sitting there manually editing each question...

Comment: I think that behind-the-scenes, it adds that during formatting of the output, and the actual title doesn't change.

Comment: -1 for cryptic abbreviations. The point of the suggestion is to make titles *more* clear, not less!

Comment: @RichieHindle: I could have looked up some favicons for example, but I just wanted to give examples for my concept. Anyway, thank you for explaining your downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with this. I know what you mean, wanting to know why, but it's really only a click away.

Titles are already long as it is, and adding even more fluff to a title will just get in the way.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that this is another in the line of "should tags be duplicated in titles" and I think that if we're not duplicating "feature-request" etc in titles, then we shouldn't duplicate closed state either. What's wrong with a tag to indicate closed state?

Comment: I really don't care *where* it's stored. I'd just like a way to get the information for a whole list of questions without clicking through on each one. It's a small thing, really... i suppose i could always write a Greasemonkey script... ;-)

Comment: I totally see your point. Where IS greasemonkey when you need him?