# Can we make the title of duplicate questions say "duplicate"?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, duplicate-questions, title

I love that posts closed as Off Topic and migrated to another site [now say **[migrated]**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/please-append-the-reason-for-closing-to-the-title-along-with-closed/7081#7081).

Can we do this for a **[duplicate]** as well?  The distinction between a question closed as duplicate and one that is closed as not a real question, too localized, or otherwise "bad" is at least as big or maybe even bigger than those that are migrated.

Unless the original is *also* closed, then the duplicate is *just as valid* but already answered — and this would prevent users browsing the question lists from assuming anything else about the question (such as *Weird, maybe X is off topic here*?)

Comment: also, [merged] wouldn't hurt

Comment: How about making the title say [[sic](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24750/how-do-you-quote-a-passage-that-has-used-sic-mistakenly)]?

Comment: yes please do this pretty please

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is a thing that we do now:

[image]

Comment: Go on, tell us how you do it.

Comment: @ChrisF I have no idea. Magic and some C#?

Comment: You can do better than that :)

Comment: Magic, C# and SQL I bet

Comment: @BenBrocka SQL *is* magic.

Comment: My little Database SQL is Magic

Comment: The query is already being done to determine what something was closed as, so the result is memoized and reused for the title suffix.  [MEMOIZATION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), F*&$ YEAH!

Comment: Also, brace yourselves for more changes around duplicates.

Comment: And if some database changes were involved, then maybe adding a search option `duplicate:yes` is doable too? (Next to the existing `closed:` and `migrated`. I have no idea if that is useful though...)

Comment: Shouldn't it say "duplicated" with a "d" to match "closed" and "migrated"?

Comment: @animuson No: the closed question is the duplicate, it's the other question that's duplicated.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Like [this](http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3soc66/)?

Comment: This is great, because it's more conciliatory than "closed", but has the same effect.

Comment: @Arjan a search operator isn't in the plans, yet, but it might be.  One would have to plead with Nick Craver to add it to the elastic search models :)

Answer (score 2):

If the only problem is extra DB lookups, how about literally modifying question title to add "[duplicate]" string instead? There's hardly any chance they'll be reopened back and need any editing, so this won't get in anyone's way. Yes, "[duplicate] [closed]" looks heavier, but I'd be willing to look over it to see duplicates at a glance. Or it can even be cut down with site JS or userscript.

And even in a miniscule amount of cases when such a question is somehow reopened it is still small feat to remove it manually or system can even clean-up this automatically too.

Comment: The code still needs to make an extra query, to know the closing reason. The migration date is saved in the "Posts" table, but the closing reason (e.g. off-topic, not constructive, not a real question) is saved in a different table.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, it seems you didn't understood: on closing, "title" column should be modified by appending literal " [duplicate]" suffix to it. Displaying title with those words in it, naturally, doesn't require any more lookups that any other title.

Comment: That's a non-robust and non-semantic approach that would not pass code review in my team.

Answer (score 1):

No -- not without incurring one SQL query per every displayed element on the page.

`[migrated]` was possible because we store a `MigrationDate` on the posts table. There is only `CloseDate`; to get the *reason* for the close we would have to dig into the post history table which is massive.

I don't feel this feature is so important it is worth that amount of performance and engineering work at this time.

Comment: That's very reasonable.  We need more performance.  But would it be reasonable to include close reasons in the Posts table or is that change too costly to do right now?

Comment: I get that it's expensive. But when you look at a lower-volume site with a lot of closing (eg programmers.se) the [closed] markers are telling what's welcome here and what's not. When things are closed as dupes they look unwelcome, which they're not. I think the "first impression" is better when dupes are marked as such.

Comment: While the "programmer time" argument might be valid (although I'd personally consider it worth it, and would volunteer to help if I could), the performance impact could be easily eliminated, at the cost of a small amount of database denormalization, by adding a `CloseReasonId` column to the posts table.  It could even be populated gradually by a background job.

Comment: Ps. In hindsight, it would probably have been better to use a `CloseHistoryId` column, pointing to the appropriate row in the PostHistory table, instead of `CloseDate`. That would've required an extra (left) join to get the closing date, but would've made all the other information in the history row just as easily accessible. I suppose it still wouldn't be too late to switch...

Comment: How easy would it be to check the post body to see if it starts with "Possible Duplicate"?