# Show close reasons on front page/in search results

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we make the title of duplicate questions say “[duplicate]”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90672/can-we-make-the-title-of-duplicate-questions-say-duplicate)

Observe:

[image: *important screenshot*]

Notice how there's no indication about why this question was closed? That's what I'd like to see changed. In this case, it would be nice if instead of **[closed]** it said **[closed: off-topic]**. Other questions should be treated analogously.

This would, at least, make it easier to assess questions found in searches, etc.: a dupe or migrated question is likely to be rather more useful than the "votes"/"answers" would seem to indicate, in that one can then go to the linked questions/site...

Comment: It's customary when making a feature request to explain how that feature request would add value to the site.

Comment: ...but +1 for "Jeff wuz cranky."  Made me laugh.

Comment: `[migrated]` was recently implemented.

Comment: @Jon: yeah, I may have seen that. I can't remember...

Comment: As Jon mentioned, showing [migrated] is implemented, but the rest is covered by the dupe.