# Bounty messages "*bump*" and "Bump!" are dropped silently

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, bounty-remarks

I tried to create bounties with the custom messages `*bump*` and `Bump!`.

[image]

They seemed to be submitted normally,

[image] [image]

but the messages were silently dropped.

[image]
[image]

The only other message I tested was "`*test* test`", which appeared as expected:

[image]

Are short messages supposed to be blocked? If so, can this be reflected in the interface like it is for comments, rather than just silently dropping input in one of the few cases where it can't be edited later?

Comment: Is there a minimum length perhaps, that's only enforced on the server side?

Comment: How about putting a **real** message in there?

Comment: Bounty on the [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) o_O' ?!? Oy! Everything all right?

Comment: @RobertHarvey How about suggesting that to users while it's still an option?

Comment: True - other limitations don't simply ignore input - they will warn the user...

Comment: It's an *optional* field. Submitting a horrible message just makes the system think, "Well then, I guess you *don't* want to add a message."

Comment: `*bump*` is a "horrible" message? ;)

Comment: @Mat That was just a test for this post, with the HTTP activity monitor open so I could verify that it wasn't client-side. The original bounty was on [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90672/can-we-make-the-title-of-duplicate-questions-say-duplicate).

Comment: Pop, pop! Eh, I got nothing.

Comment: @sixlettervariables you called?

Comment: Ah, I love these little features. It brings a smile to my face to imagine Jeff writing code to silently drop bounty messages that include the word "bump".

Comment: [​](http://google.com)ß​ÜMP

Comment: @the this seems like a bug, generally we enforce minimum message lengths with a visible warning

Comment: we use the same renderer as comments, the renderer is stripping it if it is not a "minimum comment length" ... will ensure we check it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Back in day one I had some code that suppressed notices shorter than 10 chars from being displayed. They are actually stored in the DB.

I just changed it so we do a simple test to ensure we stop you from submitting anything shorter than 30. A message shorter than 30 makes no sense in this context.