# In search, mark closed-as-dupe questions as such

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we make the title of duplicate questions say “[duplicate]”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90672/can-we-make-the-title-of-duplicate-questions-say-duplicate)

Multiple times I'm searching for stuff on MSO/whatever, I come across questions marked `[closed]` in the search results. Normally, I steer clear of closed(CV-as-anything-but-dupe) questions since they're usually useless, but I still have to check those CV'd as duplicates since they provide some valuable information.

At least in the search results, could we mark them as `[closed(dupe)]` or `[duplicate]`?

Comment: This makes sense as questions that are [migrated] are noted as such.