# Repeated closed/duplicate annotations in question title

Tags: bug, status-completed, homepage

Best demonstrated with a screenshot:

[image]

Pretty sure there were less of them earlier.  The question itself has just the single annotation.

Comment: That should have been `[triplicate]`.

Comment: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` gone bad, maybe?

Comment: developers developers

Comment: I just saw one with closed repeated 10 times

Comment: Too bad a question, one close is not enough..

Comment: To be fair enough questions get closed on meta that you would have thought every possible  scenario would have been thoroughly tested...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was related to a [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164651/3) I made to question titles...

... and the problem was caching*, always caching!

On the home page, we cache a list of recent question objects in ASP.NET's [HttpRuntime.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx), which subsequent requests will use to render your interesting questions.

These question objects have a `NiceTitle` property that will append those [closed], [duplicate], [migrated] status suffixes, and the code went something like this:

```
var suffix = GetQuestionStateSuffix();
if (suffix.HasValue())
    Title += " " + suffix;
return Title;
```

This worked fine in testing; the homepage looked as beautiful as ever.  It looked beautiful because none of the normal homepage code used this `NiceTitle`. **

Mobile, on the other hand, does use it.  And this is where the intermittent bug came in.  Those cached objects kept getting their `Title` happily overwritten each time a mobile user rendered a closed question's summary.

The fix is in and deployed - totally my bad.

<sub>* and a misguided assignment statement :)</sub>

<sub>** please don't ask why every rendered Title isn't done through NiceTitle... please.</sub>

Comment: Brace-less `if` block? *shudders*

Comment: Abbreviated for publication :P

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ braces take up hard drive space. He's just being  conservative.