# "Top questions" item lists "[​closed] [​closed] [​closed] [​closed]"

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Repeated closed/duplicate annotations in question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164799/repeated-closed-duplicate-annotations-in-question-title)

I guess [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382665/cvcamshifttracker-object-initialization-for-tracking) is really closed, huh?

[image: closed closed closed closed]

Comment: bwahaha love the [duplicate] on the end of this - I know, it belongs, but bwa hahaha

Comment: I noticed you voted to close your own Q...why not just delete? Just curious. Love the reason given for this problem in the duplicate's Answer.

Comment: @AKTed: Uncontrollable nostalgia and a habit for hoarding.