# Can we put the close reason in the question title?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please append the reason for closing to the title along with “Closed”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/please-append-the-reason-for-closing-to-the-title-along-with-closed)
>   [Can we make the title of duplicate questions say "duplicate"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90672/can-we-make-the-title-of-duplicate-questions-say-duplicate)

I don't know if there is any technical reason which prohibits this, but it would make it easier to scan down the list of questions and communicates more information than [closed], which could have been applied for a number of different reasons.

Examples from the current top questions:

- Icon idea for “project” [closed: offtopic]
- Silverlight + Expression Blend = Good UX? [closed: not constructive]
- Bringing computer icons into the future: Is it too disruptive to UX? [closed: exact duplicate]

Comment: And maybe also have a gray background on closed questions which would make them look more like in a disabled state.

Comment: This is more of a general question on the StackExchange platform itself rather than one specific to ux.se. I'll migrate it to the main meta.stackoverflow site so you can get feedback from the wider community.

Comment: IIRC this was declined for performance reasons; there's only one check for "is closed" and the developers didn't consider it worth the speed hit to include the close reason

Comment: I don't see the benefit here. Closed is closed and often questions have multiple problems with them that makes the exact reason given little more than the tossing of a coin.

Comment: @ChrisF I don't see that reason in that answer - all I see is "edit: my reason for declining this was bunk".

Comment: Sorry - wrong questions - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90672/can-we-make-the-title-of-duplicate-questions-say-duplicate is the one I should have linked to.

Comment: Ah, that clears it up. Thank you. :)