# For migrated questions, append {migrated} to the title, instead of {closed}

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

Using [migrated] makes more sense, as the question isn't actually "closed" per se, as it still exists somewhere in the Trilogy. When I see [closed] I just mentally ignore it and move on, but there's no reason to ignore migrated questions... just follow them through to their proper site.

**New:**

E: Running into this again (I think it's the same case), going to try and get this some attention. Here's another case where this matters:

Guess what happens when I click [this *presumably valid* link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve-closed) in my profile? Anyone?

[image]

Well I do get redirected to [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42371/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve), where I guess the question was moved to, but what's this? Oh, **a useless 404 >:(**

[image]

The fact that questions can disappear like this but leave "working" links is *really really really* annoying.

Comment: This sounds familiar... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/please-append-the-reason-for-closing-to-the-title-along-with-closed/7081#7081 ;-)

Comment: Oh, and just so you know, a variant of this (see link above) has been declined, but maybe this proposal would work instead.

Comment: This is where I initially proposed it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6975/favourited-migrated-questions-appear-as-having-no-answers/6977#6977

Comment: Not surprised that it's been suggested, but I *did* look before I posted

Comment: +1, though I think it should be [woooosh] in lieu of [migrated].

Comment: +1 found the post when I was about to propose the same thing.

Comment: This suggestion ought to be reconsidered.

Comment: Now that '[closed]' questions lead you to the migrated question, I think it is even more important than before to tag the question as '[migrated]'.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet, but I think [migrate] is a more better tag than [close].  As a new user to the Stack Exchange eco system, you guys and gals geeking out over the architecture of the sites seem overzealous in your defense thereof and I'm not entirely sure why and it's kind of hard to figure things out.

Answer (score 22):

There are two different things we want to say to the users.

1. You will find the answers not here but elsewhere -> migrated to...
2. You can't edit this question -> [closed]

In my opinion point 1 is much more important for the casual user than point 2.
I'm primarily interested in the answers.

To find the answers I have to scroll down, parse three confusing lines (migrated, locked, closed) and click on the URL of another website (e.g. superuser.com) with no indication that it leads me to the answers. I doubt that new users grok that.

---

My proposal is to put point 1 in the title and make it a link to the question.
For example:

> Best IT (non-development) forum [[migrated to superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/12109/best-it-non-development-forum)]

If this is too long maybe:

> Best IT (non-development) forum [[migrated to SU](https://superuser.com/questions/12109/best-it-non-development-forum)]

Or even:

> Best IT (non-development) forum [[migrated to [image]](https://superuser.com/questions/12109/best-it-non-development-forum)]

Handle point 2 in the footer of the question.

> closed and migrated by Espo, SilentGhost, David Dorward, phoenix, sharptooth Jul 24 at 11:29

---

[closed] is a sign of the bad quality of a question, I don't read closed questions, and I don't care about the close reason. 
This is not true for migrated questions. Just because a question was posted on the wrong site doesn't say anything about its quality.

Therefore "migrated" shouldn't be another close reason, but handled specially.
In other words the [close] is just a side effect of the migration, what's important is the migration.

Answer (score 9):

Now that we have a lot more migrations across the network, I will look into this.

One tricky bit: it pulls across a field we may or may not have pre-loaded for a Post, namely `MigrationDate` so it could have some toxic side-effects.

Comment: e.g. [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86887/146482)?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a link in the closed (migrated) question to the moved question on superuser/ server fault etc?

Or am I just not seeing it?

Comment: The link is the <site name> in "migrated to <site name>", but it could be made more obvious.