# Show on 'other site' switch

Tags: feature-request, cross-posting, site-crossover

Feature request / idea:

Sometimes a question seems to fall in between two sites.  An example might be [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) email questions, could be the code or could be the php.ini which often ends up being a system administrator.

So my idea is that there could be a check box to show it on another site as well. It would be grayed out on the other site and only visible to people with high reputation points, and they could approve it, and then everyone would be able to see it on the other site as well. Maybe they could add answers, or maybe it would just be visible and people could go to the other site to add the answers.

So for example, if the question was posted on Stack Overflow, there could be a 'show on Server Fault' check box. Which Server Fault  moderators / high reputation points users could vote to be shown there as well. These could also maybe be community-wiki so simplify the reputation points question.

One downside I can think of is that maybe this might create more confusion about what to put what where worse, and maybe that would outweigh any benefits.

Maybe it has been thought of, but I just thought I would share the idea...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Question types need to be restricted to one site. It becomes way too confusing to follow if different answers to the same question are present all over the place. It would be more useful to define what questions belong where -- and place them in that location consistently, rather than having a dizzying web of interconnections that only Sherlock Holmes could trace.

Comment: May be answers made on one site could appear in both sites... I had your same reaction when reading the feature-request, but it actually makes some sense.

Comment: Watson could do it too, give him more credit...

Comment: Make answers made on one site appear on both other sites would be very confusing. What we need is in my opinion easier navigation to the answers. Suggested the details there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10641/instead-of-closed-for-migrated-questions-migrated/12798#12798

Comment: Once this gets 10 votes, I will accept that answer as 'No, this is a bad idea' :-)

Answer (score 1):

I worry that people might get into the habit of clicking off all three (four?) sites under the SO umbrella.  It's not a terrible idea, by any stretch, but I'm not a fan.

Comment: Well, use 'radio' boxes so only one can be checked, or whatever they are called.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of folks carry accounts on more than one site. I suspect that your audience---in your hypothetical this would be web administrators who know PHP and programmers who know how to configure web scripting engines---will mostly have a presence on both sites.

So take your best guess for which to post it on and don't worry too much about it, no?