# Could we please get some UI differentiation for locked posts?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, information-display, locked

A few times I've tried to do something on a closed post, and found that it was actually locked.  The migrated ones don't show locked status.

Could we get some kind of UI indication that it's a locked post?
Maybe a border around the question,
or a set of jailbars on top of it?

Please recommend ideas.

Comment: ...but the migrated ones do say they are migrated, in very large letters.

Comment: yep, and with enough bad clicks, I may finally remember someday, but shouldn't a good UI, not force you to remember little details like that?

Comment: I would've agreed with @Robert if I hadn't just made that exact mistake in the last minute or so; I tried to vote on a migrated post

Comment: Huh... you still get the Edit and Close options on a locked post? I've only got >500 so I can only retag, and that's not visible on a locked post. Weird for such an inconsistency.

Comment: IIRC, there was a feature-request to put [migrated] instead of [closed] on migrated questions (declined, again IIRC). Perhaps that could be followed with locked posts -- although a post can be in multiple states at once (i.e., open, closed, locked, closed + locked, locked + migrated).

Comment: Maybe they could just disable the features you can use if locked (like voting triangles, edit links, etc).

Comment: @Jon http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10641/instead-of-closed-for-migrated-questions-migrated It was indeed declined.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, how about we just replaced the **[closed]** text with **[locked]** since all locked questions also have all the characteristics of closed ones, i.e. closed is a subset of locked.

[image: Mockup example of locked post]

Comment: but then how would you know if it was eligible to be reopened?

Comment: @Rich, can you vote to reopen a locked question?

Comment: Locked is more restrictive than closed. You can't vote on, comment or edit a locked post.

Comment: +1.  Sometimes questions are locked without being closed, which gives no indication on the question list.  Adding [locked] solves this, too.

Answer (score 5):

I could go for a different background colour, similar to how a magenta background is used for deleted posts.  Pale green is chromatically opposite, and would be obvious enough, unless you're red-green colourblind perhaps?

**Edit**: how about a pale blue? It evokes a sense of iciness -> frozen -> YOU SHALL NOT PASS.

Comment: I'm mixed in colors, but green is probably unwise... didn't that used to be the color for approved posts, back when they were highlighted?

Comment: If it was so long ago you can't quite remember... perhaps it's time it can be reused again.

Answer (score 4):

I would think that a grayish color on the background may be appropriate. But really I just recommend removing all of the editing buttons that can't be used on locked posts such as the voting triangles. Maybe they could be hollow or greyed out or gone entirely(and definitely not clickable).

And then of course removing the retag/edit/whatever buttons which can't be used. I think that may be a bug for 10k users though because being 5k I don't see the edit button even though I can edit unlocked posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think I need some specific examples of where you've tried to do something with a locked post, and why.

I just want to understand the motivations here.

Comment: I think the incident that triggered this one, was me trying to vote on a locked post, like I would be able to do on a closed one.

Comment: For http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74129/can-i-get-the-source-code-of-stack-overflow-closed I wanted to address the specifics of the question (ie, that the mentioned site is an old stackexchange site, etc) so the OP has some direct closure, since the merged/migrated to question answers only part of his question.