# Comment on closed questions broken?

Tags: bug, comments, closed-questions, locked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we please get some UI differentiation for locked posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51498/could-we-please-get-some-ui-differentiation-for-locked-posts)

Why am I unable to comment on the following closed question:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74129/can-i-get-the-source-code-of-stack-overflow-closed

It was migrated from SO, but appears to be closed with no close reason or notice as to who did it.

More troubling, I cannot add comments.

Bug, or have I simply been away from here for too long, and this is the new thingadongdong?

Comment: It's locked. Which happened because it was merged. Which probably would have been indicated below the question, except this space was already taken up by the "migrated" indicator. FWIW, this appears to be a duplicate of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51498/could-we-please-get-some-ui-differentiation-for-locked-posts

Comment: The lineage of this question confuses me... Hrm... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74136/comment-on-closed-questions-broken - Ah, now I understand.  Confusing to say the least.

Comment: Did you link to yourself?

Comment: @srachenstern - Why yes, I did.  I meant to link the revisions of the question in the op: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/74129/revisions