# A new look for locked questions?

Tags: support, locked-questions

Is the SE team hard at work tweaking the UI for locked questions, or is the web proxy at my job randomly blocking stuff?

[image]

Comment: If the former, then it would make sense, I think. Sort of like locking the voting as well.

Comment: Did you think there would be a ruckus for four straight days and SE wouldn't make *any* changes?

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  The best solution to this content has always been to make it look distinct and different -- you're not in regular Stack Overflow anymore.

Comment: They have indeed gone, voting on historical stuff makes no sense. [tag:feature-request]: Can the team please place a [historical unicorn statue](http://www.moonslightmagic.com/images/unicorn_statue.jpg) in its place? ;)

Comment: Wait for it....

Comment: @Tom - indeed.  I hope they go even further...

Comment: If that's an attempt to make historical questions look different, it will only work for veteran users. New users don't know what active questions and answers are "supposed" to look like.

Comment: @Robert - I'm sure it's just a start.  I'd say move the historical banner text up above the question title, *emphasize it*, fade the colors *slightly*, and so on

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51498/could-we-please-get-some-ui-differentiation-for-locked-posts

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is something we're experimenting with for truly "historical" questions (that is, questions and answers which no longer benefit from *any* interaction). They are effectively frozen in time, a record of something that happened and still has some meaning but is no longer a living, breathing part of the site.

More to come...

Comment: +1 This train of thoughts is good, instead of throwing a warning at us because you gave the link to us you can just hide the link from us. I'm hoping to see this in other places too... :)

Comment: @Shog9: But the real question is, will these "historical" questions still remove reputation as if they were deleted?

Comment: @animuson - I would hope the point of all this is to obviate the need to delete them in the first place.

Comment: +1 for making an effort to keep historical items around.

Answer (score 5):

It's not just you.

Voting is currently disabled completely on closed questions (maybe allowed in some cases), there's a class on voting buttons

```
.ice-ice-baby .votecell .vote-up-off, .ice-ice-baby .votecell .vote-down-off { display:none }
```

(`.ice-ice-baby` means that the question is closed) blocking it

When I tried to "show" it with Chrome inspection tool and tried to vote up, this popup appeared

```
This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on.
```

Comment: I think you're mixing [some terminology](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13059/post-locked-vs-post-closed) here. The above certainly does not apply to [all **closed** questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1), and not even to all [locked questions](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1ceAN.png).

Comment: @Arjan: I think I'm not. Read my answer again and this snippet, too: `(maybe allowed in some cases),`, which is saying it all.

Comment: More like: maybe *not* allowed in some cases? Really, all of the **closed** questions I've looked at *do* show the voting icons and allow for voting. Do you have any example that proves otherwise? If not, then read your answer again ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: this feature has been removed, once again. My answer was valid before 20 hours..

Comment: Ah, that explains things! (Well, it was valid for one hour and 15 minutes then, until I posted my comment...)