# Vote buttons missing

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A new look for locked questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124692/a-new-look-for-locked-questions)

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295955/what-is-the-most-useful-r-trick) the upvote and downvote buttons are missing! What's wrong?
Is that because the answer is locked? Or closed? Is that some kind of new feature? I'm logged in.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post in question is locked, so one can't vote on it.

Comment: since when? This must be new "feature"!!