# Burninate the vague tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

Does the [vague](/questions/tagged/vague) tag serve any useful purpose at all?  Can we burninate it?

[image]

Comment: Don't know why you did this, I'll make 15 rep off the accepted answer alone, which counters the rep you make from the question (at this point, you have three votes, and *I* even gave you one), and every vote I get is double what you get.  But I like that you give guys a fighting chance, so kudos!

Comment: I love how these creep in. No objections here if someone feels like removing it. Better question is, is it a candidate to become a synonym for something, or does it need to be blacklisted for now?

Comment: @Tim - I don't have much of an imagination, but I can't think of any possible synonym for it.  This tag seems fundamentally useless.

Comment: -1 for even questioning whether `vague` could serve a useful purpose :P

Comment: @Matthew - HA - so *you're* the one who downvoted this post.  Of all the stuff I've posted here, I didn't expect a -1 *here* :)

Comment: @MatthewRead Ha,just for that I will start a project named `libvague`, with the client of course being `vague`. I'll dump a bunch of LISP into the repo, push it to github and then grow a neckbeard just so I can stroke it as I chuckle.

Comment: @TimPost Diabolical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only 28 questions tagged as [vague](/questions/tagged/vague) I've gone through and manually removed it from all of them.

[image]

It shouldn't be popping up again.  If it does, we can remove it, or if it does aggressively, we can look into synonyms or blacklisting it.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering. I can't think of a possible mate for a synonym. Probably just needs to be blacklisted, if nobody else can think of one in the next couple of days.

Comment: Are you [forgetting something](http://i.imgur.com/4oDjC.png)??  Protocol damnit!

Comment: Done, and I'm going to kick up all the other tag posts that I've made and edit them to include this, bumping them to the front page of meta and getting *more* votes.  Thank you!

Comment: Looks like your one rep point below me.  **Pressure!!!**

Comment: @AdamRackis Four above, learn to count.

Comment: @casper - *six* above, **you** learn to count...

Comment: @AdamRackis Ha! And I wasn't even the one to downvote you.

Comment: @AdamRackis BTW, I need to template this answer, it's such an easy rep-whoring tool.

Comment: Odd that we're both getting downvotes on this post - do people just really love the vague tag?

Comment: @AdamRackis Ouch!  WTF?!?  Perhaps they think we're colluding...

Comment: Colluding?!  That's frankly insulting.  If we were colluding we'd do it *much* more intelligently than this.

Comment: @Adam-aka-2nd-in-command-to-casperOne I agree.  The accusation makes me puke in my mouth a little.

Comment: Second in command???  Might want to check our rep numbers again...

Comment: @AdamRackis I'm up by 34 as of this comment...

Comment: Damnit - ok - guess you're on top again.  There's only one way to settle this - I challenge you to a duel.  Pistols, 20 yards, Battery Park at dusk.

Comment: @AdamRackis You're in *my* city?  I thought you were in CO?  And please don't ever use the phrase "you're on top again" lest you want my eyes to bleed. =P

Comment: *sigh* - I wish I was in your city (my city too).  I'll be back in a few months to visit, so we can go Hamilton/Burr then.  And good call on the terminology  :-O

Comment: @AdamRackis From NYC originally?  I respect that.  Ping me when you're in town and we'll get lit/crunk/whatever the kids are calling it nowadays.

Comment: From upstate, but I always took the train down to the real NY whenever I could growing up.  I will ping you, but I hope you realize what you've gotten yourself into now...

Comment: @AdamRackis I'm from the BX, I'll survive.

Comment: There's a vague question I want to tag.  I just googled and found this discussion.  Curses!  *the vague tag is gone!*