# Should the historical lock feature be applied to old historical deleted questions?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, locked-questions, historical-lock

This is a continuation of [my old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114908/155556) based on the [new locking feature discussed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124692/155556).
The same goes for questions on the [popular deleted questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73455/155556)

Should those **deleted** historical questions be reinstated with the new lock feature?

Comment: +1: Remember that most popular deleted posts were necessarily mod-deleted, so users cannot use undeletion votes to directly show support.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The entire argument in favor of deleting these fun and, frankly useless questions has always been that they created broken windows.  They set bad examples of what's acceptable on Stack Overflow; they polluted the top question lists, crowding out legitimate questions; etc.

The [new lock format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124692/a-new-look-for-locked-questions) the team has come up with eliminates these concerns.  Un-delete them, and lock them.

Answer (score 13):

If it's a useful resource that:

1. was linked heavily from outside Stack Overflow
2. is not available somewhere else on the Internet
3. was content created by Stack Overflow community members

I wouldn't have a problem with undeleting and locking an old post.  If it's just a list of links to favorite cartoons or t-shirts that were created by other people, I'd probably let it rest in peace.

**Note:** These are just my personal guidelines for applying the historical lock or deleting a post.  It's ultimately up to the community, so vote accordingly.

Comment: Well how does the community know *1* or *2*, also if it is on Stack Overflow would it not be correct that the content was created by Stack Overflow community members?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Google will tell you if 1 or 2 apply.  And no, a list of links to cartoons is not content created by community members, it's content created by cartoonists.

Comment: Well not ***all*** are links to cartoons :-P. Some could be viable.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA I should point out that there are exceptions to the rules.  The list of freely available programming books fails #3 above, but it's so *exceedingly* useful and heavily linked that I think it deserves a lock.  I guess some balancing has to be done, but these are the things that I look at.

Comment: That is quite true. But who is the one to "`look at it`" and decides what stays and what goes? Shouldn't that be up to a community vote?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Ah, I think I see what you're getting at now.  Yes, the community should be able to vote on these.  If something is locked in a deleted state, flag it so we can unlock it so people can vote on it.  (Can you vote to undelete posts deleted by mods?)

Comment: I think people will run into 'mod block' on some of these, as it _was_ mods that deleted the majority of the older questions that just didn't fit any longer. As @Jeremy noted, the community can't vote to reverse that. In that case they'll just have to flag for the lock/banner to be applied, but it'll have to be at our discretion (there's simply no other way to handle it, that I can think of)

Comment: @BilltheLizard We cannot vote to undelete when a mod has deleted the post.... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125762/should-the-historical-lock-feature-be-applied-to-old-historical-deleted-question/125769#comment339775_125762

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Rules on top of rules on top of rules... I agree with Tim, though.  Go ahead and flag them and we'll take a look.

Comment: Normal voters can't undelete a mod-deleted post. While reviewing deletions, I've been leaving some of these undeleted and unlocked, with a view toward letting the community vote to delete or undelete as they see fit. Note that since delete/undelete votes are capped at 10 now, this doesn't present the same problem it did in the recent past - many of these were moderator-deleted purely because they could effectively never get enough community votes otherwise.