# [Moved] not [Closed]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Display where has the question been migrated on the title instead of just [closed] (this q isn’t closed!)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6022/display-where-has-the-question-been-migrated-on-the-title-instead-of-just-closed)
>   [Favourited, migrated questions appear as having no answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6975/favourited-migrated-questions-appear-as-having-no-answers)

If a question has been closed in stack overflow it is not possible to know without opening the question if it was a bad question or a good question that has been moved to one of the other sites.

I suggest that questions that have been moved have a [Moved] tag put next to the question, and possibly that that tag be clickable and take you straight to the question in the new site.

Comment: Sure this has been asked before.

Comment: Found it - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6022/display-where-has-the-question-been-migrated-on-the-title-instead-of-just-closed - marked as [status-declined]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6975/favourited-migrated-questions-appear-as-having-no-answers

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/please-append-the-reason-for-closing-to-the-title-along-with-closed

Comment: 6022 is an exact duplicate... but possibly the data structures have now changed in the underlying database? I got the impression there was nothing 'normal' left in the db :D The others are similarish but not exactly what I asked.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10641/instead-of-closed-for-migrated-questions-migrated [status-declined] with no explanation. Though I am sure it would be the same as before! Ah well another BRILLIANT idea of mine not only thought of before by someone else, but also not going to be acted upon :D story of my life ;)

Comment: now implemented!